# Sliding Carousel - Pagination not directing to correct location

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, slider, carousel

My carousel has been built so that it slides to the next frame automatically every 5 seconds, for which I have written:

```
var carousel = $('.carousel ul:first');
var pagination = $('.carousel ul:last');

function slide01() {
  carousel.delay(5000).animate({'margin-left':'-100%'}, function() {
    pagination.find('li').removeClass('on');
    pagination.find(':nth-child(2)').addClass('on');
  });
  slide02();
};

function slide02() {
  carousel.delay(5000).animate({'margin-left':'-200%'}, function() {
    pagination.find('li').removeClass('on');
    pagination.find(':nth-child(3)').addClass('on');
  });
  slide03();
};

function slide03() {
  carousel.delay(5000).animate({'margin-left':'-300%'}, function() {
    pagination.find('li').removeClass('on');
    pagination.find(':nth-child(4)').addClass('on');
  });
  slide04();
};

function slide04() {
  carousel.delay(5000).animate({'margin-left':'0%'}, function() {
    pagination.find('li').removeClass('on');
    pagination.find(':nth-child(1)').addClass('on');
  });
  slide01();
};

slide01();
```

While this is working, I'm having difficulties with the pagination buttons. They respond but instead of going to its appropriate page, it's going to the next page, which you can view in my **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaWaheed/wfvpt/8/)**.

This is the code I have written for each button:

```
pagination.find('li:nth-child(1)').click(function(){
  carousel.stop().animate({'margin-left':'0%'});
});

pagination.find('li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
  carousel.stop().animate({'margin-left':'100%'});
});

pagination.find('li:nth-child(3)').click(function(){
  carousel.stop().animate({'margin-left':'200%'});
});

pagination.find('li:nth-child(4)').click(function(){
  carousel.stop().animate({'margin-left':'300%'});
});
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure why that is happening, but you need to refactor this code. A separate function for each slide does not make this slider very extensible :(

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into how it can be better written :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your Javascript code to provide your desired functionality and made it more extendable. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
var carousel = $('.carousel ul:first');
var pagination = $('.carousel ul:last');
var slideWidth = 200;
var autoSlideTiming = 5000;
var timeout = null;

// Buttons
$.each(pagination.children(), function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
        pagination.find('li.on').removeClass('on');
        //if you wanted to find the width dynamically
        //var slideWidth = $(this).parent().parent().find('ul:eq(0) li:eq('+i+')').width();
        carousel.stop().animate({'margin-left': -(i * slideWidth)});
        $(this).addClass('on');
    });
});

// Slider
function advanceSlide(){
   var currIndex = $(".pagination li.on").index();
   var nextIndex = ((pagination.children().length - 1) == currIndex) ? 0 : (currIndex + 1); 
   carousel.animate({'margin-left': -(nextIndex * slideWidth)}, function() {
        pagination.find('li.on').removeClass('on');
        pagination.find(':nth-child('+(nextIndex + 1)+')').addClass('on');
       timeout = setTimeout(function(){advanceSlide()}, autoSlideTiming);
    });   
}

$('.carousel').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);    
}, function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){advanceSlide()}, autoSlideTiming);
});
//init auto slide
timeout = setTimeout(function(){advanceSlide()}, autoSlideTiming);
```

Also here is an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5jEZ/1/)

**Explanation**

The [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is a jQuery utility function that works like a normal `for` loop (I would actually recommend a vanilla JavaScript `for` loop if you know how). This `$.each` accepts 2 arguments: a collection (`pagination.children()` in our case, which is an array of the `li`'s), and a callback function. This callback function passes in `i` which is our zero-based index of the collection. So, it's not 1, 2, 3, 4 but 0, 1, 2, 3. In this loop `this` is each `li`, which it is attaching a click event that handles removing and applying your `on` class and also the animation. The `-(i * slideWidth)` is taking the current zero-based index and multiplying it times the `slideWidth` and then getting the negative value of that result. So, the first slide `-(0 * 200)` would animate the margin-left to -0 or 0, and the second slide `-(1 * 200)` would animate the margin-left to -200, which pulls it 200 pixels in the left direction making it slide. This will allow you to had new `li`'s to your pagination and this code will still work!

The trick to making the `advanceSlide()` function dynamic, is finding what the index of the next slide is. To find out where we need to go we first must find where we are. That is what `currIndex` is for, which we find with the jQuery `index()` function, which returns the zero-based index of the `li` with the `on` class. Now the magic. The `nextIndex` variable is being set using a [ternary operator](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/conditionals-in-javascript/4/1) to find the value. A ternary is just programmer shorthand for a basic `if` then `else` statement. So if the ternary in this code was written out the normal way it would look like this:

```
var nextIndex;
if( (pagination.children().length - 1) == currIndex ){
    nextIndex = 0;
}else{
    nextIndex = currIndex + 1;
}
```

Remeber our `currIndex` is zero-based, but our collection (pagination.children()) `length` (number of items in the total collection) is not zero-based so we must minus 1 from it. Then we are checking if that value is equal to our `currIndex` because if this is the last item in our collection we need to set our `nextIndex` back to 0 so the slideshow loops back around. If it's not the last index we just add 1 to advance to the next slide. After we find that `nextIndex` we do our animation and apply our class.

I know this is a little long winded, but it's important that you fully understand the code you implement! Please let me know if you have nay further questions!

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome. Am I correct in understanding that through the 'each' function the argument 'i' registers each button as '1, 2, 3 and 4,' so when it is multiplied by 'slideWidth,' it takes the user to the appropriate location? I'm also finding it difficult to understand how the 'nextIndex' variable is working. Is it registering each 'pagination' list-item as '1, 2, 3 and 4'? Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it helped! I will update my answer to explain the parts you had questions on.

Answer (score 2):

You have a "Maximum call stack size exceeded." error. Yours `slide0X` function calls another `slide0Y` function and so on. You should invoke `slide0Y` only once the `slide0X` animation ended (inside the complete callback).

Moreover in your `click` callbacks, `margin-left` should be negative since you want to slide to the left.

BTW, I would implement a function `slideTo(slideId)` so that it will work for n slides, instead of writing a function for each slide.

Comment: Sorry for sounding naive but how can I do that?